# Color the tables using CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend, background-color

I have been trying to color the different tables in this image
[every column/row/table is suppose to be colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMnWI.png)

But I seem to have missed something, the last 3 white tables are suppose to be yellow, but when I try to add them, I either get yellow on every td, or some of them.

This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Poop.css">
    <title>DEE IS A SEXY BASTERD!!! </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>table arcoiris:</h1>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <!-- Background red-->
              <th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <!-- Background orange add rowspan 2 to make 2 rows-->
                <td id="orange" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    <!-- Background LIGHT GREEN ADD A COLSPAN 2 FOR THE OTHER 2 COLUMNS-->
        <tr id="seguanda_f">
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
<tr id="tercera_f">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="mag" rowspan="2" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="blueviolet"></td>
    <td class="blueviolet"></td>
</tr>
        </table>
        <table><tr><td>Segunda tavla usada para esta anotacion</td></tr></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css

```
div{
    width: 80%;
    height: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

table, tr{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
}

th,td { height: 20px; }

th {   background-color: red;}

#orange{ background-color: orange; }

td:nth-child(3) { background-color: yellow; }

#seguanda_f{ background-color: lightgreen; }

#tercera_f { background-color: blue; }

.blueviolet{ background-color: blueviolet;}

#mag{ background-color: magenta;}
```

I have tried to direct it using ID
#ornage > td'
#orange >td:nth-child, last-child. but still nothing.

I have tried to direct it using ID
#ornage > td'
#orange >td:nth-child, last-child. but still nothing.

I am expecting to fill the empty tables, so they are yellow

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the HTML code by adding new IDs for each of the elements to be colored yellow and then set the background color to yellow for all of them.

Updated HTML Code,

```
<h1>table arcoiris:</h1>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <!-- Background red-->
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!-- Background orange add rowspan 2 to make 2 rows-->
            <td id="orange" rowspan="2"></td>
            <td id="yellow"></td>
            <td id="yellow"></td>
            <td id="yellow"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Background LIGHT GREEN ADD A COLSPAN 2 FOR THE OTHER 2 COLUMNS-->
        <tr id="seguanda_f">
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tercera_f">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="mag" rowspan="2" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="blueviolet"></td>
            <td class="blueviolet"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Segunda tavla usada para esta anotacion</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Updated CSS Code,

```
#yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```